# Comment mention not being saved

Tags: bug

I ran into a little bug right now:

My comment:

[image: edit form]

And then after I save it:

[image]

As you can see, the username and the @ sign were removed after saving.

Browser: Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit) @ OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Was that the OP? (Zeeker)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Question OP = myself, answer OP = Zeeker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010443/gitignore-all-except-file-in-sub-sub-folder

Comment: If you're the only commenter and the @ reply is to the author of the post, the @ reply is redundant, and is therefore removed by the system.

Comment: OK. I got it. Not a bug then! But for longer discussions on comments this wouldn't be bad? I mean, other people are arguing about something and then you want to address your comment directly to OP, the message will be misplaced on the context of the discussion.

Comment: Just remove the @.... The main purpose of the whole @ system is for notifications.